# check if the select statement contain a text and then change it with another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

i'm new in MySql ^_^ ,

i'm using an existing openSource called GLPI , they re using the MVC method , so i found it very difficult to edit the main code , that's why i decided to post this question if i can just change the select statment from MySql instead .

so i need to know if there is any way i can keep the database listening if there is any operation contain (

```
SELECT * FROM `glpi_tickettemplates` WHERE `id` = '-2'
```

)

and then change it with 
(

```
SELECT * FROM `glpi_tickettemplates`  WHERE `id` = '1'
```

)

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this out of the box, no. Why do you need to do this in the first place? This should be fixed on application level rather than in the database

Comment: i'm using an existing openSource called GLPI , they re using the MVC method , so i found it very difficult to edit the main code

Comment: Like Pekka said that you need to fix that on application level and not database level. You can overwrite the MVC default behaviour (though not recommended for newbies) if it is something that you really need. Try finding out the Model and create a method in that model and then enter the sql in that method you just made. You can then call that method on fly to run the sql above.

Comment: @Autolycus tnks , can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question it seems that you only need this for one particular row, so why you just do not duplicate the row with id='-2' into row with id='1' and then

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON `glpi_tickettemplates`
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempTable` 
AS 
SELECT * FROM `glpi_tickettemplates` WHERE id='-2'; 
UPDATE `tempTable` SET id='1' WHERE id='-2';
REPLACE INTO `glpi_tickettemplates` SELECT * FROM `tempTable`;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `tempTable`; 
DELIMITER;
```

### Update:

If you want replace every `id='-2'` with `id='-1'` in all incoming quires, check out [MySQL Proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy).

MySQL Proxy is a simple program that sits between your client and MySQL server(s) that can monitor, analyze or transform their communication.

Its flexibility allows for unlimited uses; common ones include:

- load balancing
- failover
- query analysis
- query filtering and modification

and many more.

At http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy you find all the links to install, use and run MySQL Proxy.

Comment: tnks @FatDog47 , this can't work , becouse in the Application they are calling the records with the ( id='-2' ) , so i need something in MySQL can see if there is any oporation with ( id='-2' )  then change it with ( id='1' ) and send it after that

Comment: Then the only solution for you is http://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy . MySQL-proxy sits between your application and MySQL and can perform analyzes and modification over incoming queries.